# Doctrine - One-To-One Bidirectional Relationship not allowed

Tags: mysql, hibernate, database-design, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have a problem to transfer my databse design into Doctrine.

At first some details:

I get many football-related data from xml files and have to save it in my own database.

One part of these data are players and player statistic.

Here are my tables:

```
table: player
    id | varchar | PK
    team_id | int
    ...and many more...

table: player_statistic
    player_id | varchar | PK
    season_id | smallint | PK
    competition_id | smallint | PK
    ...and many more...
```

So the player.id is part of the composite PK from player_statistic.

In my opinion it's a one-to-one Bidirectional relationship.

Here is the relevant Entity-Code:

```
<?php
/**
  * @Entity
  * @Table(name="player")
  */
class Player
{
    /**
      * @Id
      * @OneToOne(targetEntity="PlayerStatistic", mappedBy="playerId")
      */
      private $id;

    /* ... */
}
?>

<?php
/**
  * @Entity
  * @Table(name="player_statistic")
  */
class PlayerStatistic
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Player", inversedBy="id")
     * @JoinColumn(name="player_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     private $playerId;

    /* ... */
}
?>
```

The CLI command:

```
php53 vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

returns: "An inverse association is not allowed to be identifier in 'Player#id'."

Is it generally not possible to do this, or did i something wrong?

If possible and not totaly rubbish i don't want to use extra AI PK fields.

Thanks for any kind of help.

**UPDATE**
Sorry logical problem it's a many (player_statistic) - to - one (player) Relationship.

Comment: Manuel: Did you make it work? How?

Comment: No sorry. It was a logical problem. I needed a many-to-one rs instead of a one-to-one rs